# Cannot resolve method 'createDateStringFromIntegerInput(int, int)'

Tags: android, stripe-payments

I am using Stripe and exactly copied this code from [here](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-android/blob/master/stripe/src/main/java/com/stripe/android/view/CardInputWidget.java?fbclid=IwAR0XFQEbnoACmq5yjAE1mx44ZeL3n9q9xVg_uUxGyNkvKx672STRjRC_dJM). In my android studio project, I'm getting error on this.

> createDateStringFromIntegerInput(month, year))

This is my code where I'm getting above error

```
    public void setExpiryDate(
        @IntRange(from = 1, to = 12) int month,
        @IntRange(from = 0, to = 9999) int year) {
    mExpiryDateEditText.setText(DateUtils.createDateStringFromIntegerInput(month, year));
}
```

Anyone?

Comment: `createDateStringFromIntegerInput` is defined in [DateUtils](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-android/blob/8fcd9ccb9de04b0643b1d46214229072631f4385/stripe/src/main/java/com/stripe/android/view/DateUtils.java). If you just copied the one file, you'll need to make sure DateUtils is included as well.

Comment: So you mean I should have to make a class DateUtils as defined by you?

Comment: You likely want to check that you've installed the Stripe Android SDK per https://github.com/stripe/stripe-android